# Average income by age group, for all countries?

Tags: data-request, economics, income

Is there any data source that lists average income, disposable income, or salary by age group? I would like to get something like the follows.

- Country | 25-34 | 35-44 | 45-54 | 55 and over
- Belgium | 30,000 | 33,000 | 46,000 | 52,000
- Italy | 23,000 | 32,000 | 39,000 | 51,000

The numbers are illustration purposes' only (US$). I would like to get data that includes at least 20 or so developed countries.

Of course the different age threshold can be accepted.

Answer (score 5):

This data is available from **stats.oecd.org** (for OECD countries plus Russia)

You seem to be able to get "mean disposable income" by the following age groups:

- 0 to 17
- 18 to 25
- 26 to 40
- 41 to 50
- 51 to 65
- 66 to 75
- 76+

Below is a screenshot that should help you get to the data.. unfortunately they do not have a way to save your query without logging in.

[image: stats.oecd.org screenshot]

Comment: Thanks and in fact I came across there before posting the question, but I am so dubious about the reliability of those figures. For example, mean disposable income among Japan age 18-25 is 3,017,992 while it is 2,888,827 among 26-40, which is unfeasible.

Comment: Worldbank has some coarse data on income per country. For example, see this API page: http://data.worldbank.org/developers/api-overview/income-level-queries

Answer (score 2):

If you are interested in micro-data, I think you could apply for EU-SILC data. They are survey data for EU countries, and it is the same source of data used by Eurostat, on their website.

I am not sure how hard it is to get these data and how long it takes to receive the data in case you are succesful. Bare in mind that there are restrictions though. Finally, the dataset is very big and for many countries it would be unmanageable, so you would need some external powerful server to rely on when you do analyses.